# Using find in a map just for one of the keys in a pair

Tags: stl, unordered-map, keyvaluepair

I have a map called:

```
std::unordered_map < std::string, struct > g_users
```

but I would like to enter a second key, so that I could work with:

```
std::unordered_map < std::pair < std::string, int> struct> g_users
```

Is there any way of using the find function just to look for one of the keys? If not, is there any way to filter my map according to two keys?

Comment: You might find the [Boost Multi-index Containers Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) useful.

Comment: There's no generally-useful way to have a pair of keys in an `unordered_map`: the hashing sprays them across buckets and there's no way to find values of both key types other than brute-force O(n) iteration over the entire container, or brute-force probing for all possible values of at least one of the keys (if you restrict hash/equality processing to the other key).  jotik's suggestion's better than rolling your own 2+ container solution, though it may be a little more work getting familiar with the library.